# Trying to add an AD security group as site collection admin with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, error, administration, azure-ad

I am trying to create a new SharePoint site and then add an AD security group as an additional site collection admin to that newly created site.

The only way I found to make this work is to use import-csv to create the new site and then use set-spouser with the AD group (from a variable that is really the GUID of the AD security group). The first time I run the script below, the line with set-spouser gives me an error of `"Set-SPOUser : File Not Found."`.

What is strange is when I run the script again on the same `.csv` file to create new sites, it of course skips the new-sposite line because that site was already created the first time - but - it actually adds the AD security group as a site collection admin without any errors or issues.

Anyone have an idea of why I can't do this with one script execution?

```
#Change to your tenant
$adminUrl = "https://MYDOMAIN-admin.sharepoint.com"
$userName = "me@mydomain.com"
# Let the user fill in their password in the PowerShell window
$password = Read-Host "Please enter the password for $($userName)" -AsSecureString
$ADGroupID = "6b6cbb5e-81bb-4e72-b806-709168823c20"
$LoginName = "c:0t`.c`|tenant`|$ADGroupID"
 
# Set credentials
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $password
 
# Connect to to Office 365
try{
Connect-SPOService -Url $adminUrl -Credential $credentials
write-host "Info: Connected succesfully to Office 365" -foregroundcolor green
}
catch{
write-host "Error: Could not connect to Office 365" -foregroundcolor red
Break new-SPOnlineSite
}

Import-Csv "C:\MyNewSiteCollections.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    New-SPOSite -Owner $_.Owner -StorageQuota $_.StorageQuota -Url $_.Url -NoWait -Template $_.Template -TimeZoneID $_.TimeZoneID -Title $_.Name 
    Set-SPOUser -site $_.Url -LoginName $LoginName -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
}
```

Comment: Maybe it is taking some time to create a site. Try removing `-NoWait` parameter from `New-SPOSite` **OR** try to get the site before `Set-SPOUser` using [Get-SPOSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite). Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to add site collection administrator before new site is created in your tenant.

Try removing `-NoWait` parameter from `New-SPOSite` command like:

```
Import-Csv "C:\MyNewSiteCollections.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    New-SPOSite -Owner $_.Owner -StorageQuota $_.StorageQuota -Url $_.Url -Template $_.Template -TimeZoneID $_.TimeZoneID -Title $_.Name 
    Set-SPOUser -site $_.Url -LoginName $LoginName -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $True
}
```

**Documentation**: [New-SPOSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/new-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps)

---

**OR** try to get the newly created site before using `Set-SPOUser` command. You can use `Get-SPOSite` command to get the site.

Use `Set-SPOUser` command only when you get the site instance correctly using `Get-SPOSite` command.

**Documentation**: [Get-SPOSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: I used  Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 instead on a different line, but you had the right idea about needing to wait. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add a new membership group in Active Directory

Open the Active Directory Users and Computers console.

In the navigation pane, select the container in which you want to store your group. This is typically the Users container under the domain.

Click Action, click New, and then click Group.

In the Group name text box, type the name for your new group.

In the Description text box, enter a description of the purpose of this group.

In the Group scope section, select either Global or Universal, depending on your Active Directory forest structure. If your group must include computers from multiple domains, then select Universal. If all of the members are from the same domain, then select Global.

In the Group type section, click Security.

Click OK to save your group.

Hope You Find This Useful,

Peter